# Visual Studio Code multiple open files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know this question that has been asked before but I am missing something. I am running v1.80.2 of Visual Studio Code. When I open a workspace on the left of the screen I can open a file. Then I click (or double click) on another file and it overwrites the first file. And so on, I can only see one file at a time.

I have read a number of posts which advise the solution is to double click the file name - same behaviour as single click. There are also suggestions regarding disabling private viewing. Unfortunately nothing seems to work. FWIW the file name is bolded which I gather means this is not a preview

Here are some settings I changed (something of a scatter gun approach I am afraid)

```
{
    "git.ignoreMissingGitWarning": true,
    "workbench.editor.showTabs": false,
    "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
    "git.openRepositoryInParentFolders": "never",
    "editor.rename.enablePreview": false,
    "markdown.preview.doubleClickToSwitchToEditor": false
}
```

If anyone has suggestions on how to view multiple files it would be great.

Comment: double click the tab, not the file name in the explorer. Or use command-k enter.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting there. I think my question (and understanding) was badly worded. Let me have a play and I'll post my thoughts. I can see separate tabs now but I need to confirm how I do this. Thanks all

Answer (score -1):

When you open a file, the tab should show the file name. If this text is italic, then it is not really open. It is just in a preview open mode, and the next file you open will close that tab. If you double click the italic text tab, then it should not be italic anymore, and stay open if you open another file.

You can also turn this preview off in `Workbench > Editor: Enable Preview`. Uncheck that checkbox, and you can click on files once to open them.

Comment: Thanks Adam, unfortunately my experience is unusual. I should have said BTW that I am on a windows platform. The filename is not in italics, "enable Preview" is unticked but it ain't working :(

Comment: since this is your answer, you should have dup-voted

Comment: @starball Do you want to elaborate on that, and use real words.

Comment: voted to close the question as a duplicate of the canonical Q&A. [/help/duplicates](/help/duplicates). words are "real" to those who use them. apologies for using slang you didn't know.

Comment: @starball Cheers for that. And you are probably correct. I was answering in a rush. I will delete my answer. Also an abbreviation might be understood, and fit the lexicon, but it does not make it a real word. It is an abbreviation of an actual/real word. The way I asked could come off as rude, so I'm sorry about that.